Does convergence of the expected value imply convergence in $L^1$?
Let $X$,$X_1,X_2,...$ be real-valued random variables in $L^1$ such that $X_n \to_p X$ ($X_n$ converges in probability to $X$) and such that we have for the expected values $\lim_{n\to \infty} E[X_n] = E[X]$.
Does this already imply $\lim_{n\to \infty} E[|X_n|] = E[|X|]$?

What have you tried?

Let $X_n=\pm n$ with probability $\frac2n$…

Thank you! I'll try to post an answer in the hope that I have understood your hint correctly...

No, as you can see from the following counterexample: Let (for $n\geq 4$) $\mathbb{P}(X_n=n) = \mathbb{P}(X_n=-n)=2/n$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n=0) = 1-4/n$. Then $\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>\epsilon) = 4/n$ for $0<\epsilon<n$, so $\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>\epsilon) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ for each $\epsilon>0$, so $X_n \to_p 0$. Moreover,
$$ E[X_n] = n\cdot 2/n - n\cdot 2/n = 0 \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0,$$
but
$$ E[|X_n|] = n\cdot 2/n + n\cdot 2/n = 4.$$

Looks good (+1).  Of course you may as well use Probabilities $1/n$, the factor of two is not doing anything. Or you could put the 2 factor in the denominator to allow $n\geq 1$.
